# axlsx ruby gem: is there a way to add a text box?

Tags: ruby, excel, axlsx

I would like to add a title in large type at the top of the generated spreadsheet. The equivalent of Excel's native Insert > Text Box, positioned top center.

Is there a way to achieve this via axlsx? How?

If this is impossible, what would be an alternative way to achieve such an effect?

Comment: What I have done is merge cells and create a single title cell in the first row with the desired format.But, you do need to know the right number of columns for it to look right.